# Custom dashes in matplotlib cycler

Tags: matplotlib

How would one use custom dashes in a `matplotlib` `prop_cycle`? According to the `Line2D` documentation one can use a tuple of the form `(<offset>, (<lengthon>, <lengthoff>))` as a linestyle, and indeed that works for individual plots, but when adding the same to a `cycler`, it fails (see code below).

Have I missed/misunderstood anything, or could this be a bug?

For example, this code throws `AttributeError: 'Line2D' object has no attribute '_dashSeq'`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from cycler import cycler

pc = cycler('linestyle', ['-', (0,(3,1))] )

# this works
fig,ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot([0,1],linestyle='-')
ax.plot([1,2],linestyle=(0,(3,1)))

# this fails
fig,ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_prop_cycle(pc)
ax.plot([0,1])
ax.plot([1,2])

plt.show()
```

Comment: I tried to out-smart this by using [`set_dashes`](http://matplotlib.org/api/lines_api.html#matplotlib.lines.Line2D.set_dashes) but it generates a very similar error `Unknow artist properties: set(['dashes'])`

Comment: @Schorsch Yes, I tried with dashes as well (e.g. `cycler('dashes', [[3,1],[5,2]])`). However, `dashes` won't let you plot solid lines as far as I can see, so even if it worked it wouldn't be ideal.

Comment: I posted an issue at GitHub: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/5850

Comment: @Schorsch Thomas Caswell confirmed that this is a bug, see link to GitHub above.

Comment: I was hit by probably the same bug: trying to use custom linestyle with `axvline` results in the same exception. In my case a workaround (until the bugfix is released) is to first set some other linestyle in the `axvline` call, e.g. 'solid', and afterwards change it with `set_linestyle`. I don't know if a similar workaround can be applied to the cycler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was confirmed as a bug, and should be fixed in Matplotlib 1.5.2, see https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/5850#event-517273746

Comment: In the meantime until 1.5.2 is released, you can do something like this after the fact:

ax.lines[0].set_linestyle((0,(3,1)))